# $('body').css('pointer-events', 'none'); not working in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I wanted to freeze and stop pointer events when I am loading but it doesn't work.
I have a javascript here that i want it to work.

```
function showCreate() {
    $('body').css('pointer-events', 'none');
    $("body").css("overflow", 'hidden');
    $('body').append('<div id="loadingDiv"><div class="lds"><div></div><div></div><div></div></div></div>');
    $('a[id^="btn"]').attr("onclick", 'return false;');
}
```

but it doesn't work. and i dont understand why.

```
<style type="text/css">
    body {
        pointer-events: none;
        overflow : hidden;
    }
</style>
```

I've tried hard-coding overflow and pointer events like this and it works, but it just doesn't work in javascript.

I tried changing the CSS with javascript but it still doesn't work

```
function showCreate() {
    // Get a reference to the body element
    var bodyElement = document.body;

    // Add a class to the body element
    bodyElement.classList.add('Background4');

    // Remove a class from the body element
    bodyElement.classList.remove('Background2');

    //$('body').css('pointer-events', 'none');
    //$("body").css("overflow", 'hidden');
    $('body').append('<div id="loadingDiv"><div class="lds"><div></div><div></div><div></div></div></div>');
    //$('a[id^="btn"]').attr("onclick", 'return false;');
}
```

Comment: your code is based on JQuery not javascript. The `$` sign is used in `JQuery library` not in `JavaScript`

Comment: ok i'll change the title, then what can i do to fix this ya?

Comment: Your jQuery code is fine. Most likely you don't call the showCreate function nowhere.

Comment: Are you calling `showCreate()` anywhere? You'd be able to tell by whether or not that div it creates shows up. Also, are you loading jQuery? Do any errors show in the console?

Comment: I called it in a button within the body, wait I’ll edit my question later , thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The button within body can have `onclick` attribute and call showCreate fucntion to get it working. For eg:
`<button onclick="showCreate ()">Click Me!</button>`

bonus tip: you can use chaining of jQuery function, so that you don't have to write `$('body')` on every line.